# SUM INDEX MATCH where multiple occurrences found

Tags: excel

I have 500k lines of payroll data that I am auditing and need some help with `SUM` `INDEX` `MATCH` where there are multiple entries (employee works more then one shift in a day).

I have put the data into a pivot table showing weekly hours worked, columns show day of week.

Employees get overtime on weekends, with one rate for mornings and one rate for afternoons after 12 pm, so in the source data I have added a couple of columns for morning and evening hours, calculated by formula. I have then used the index/match functions next to the pivot table to return the corresponding values

Because some employees work multiple shifts (which are on different lines in the source data) these are not getting picked up. Any ideas how I would sum all matches?

The below picture shows what the pivot table looks like, and how the data tab looks. Colored columns are helper columns I have added.

NB: the unique reference in the source data has the day included, but not in the pivot data (otherwise pivot would show daily pay not weekly) so my formula adds Saturday to the pivot reference when looking up in the source data. Not relevant to my question, but FYI as figured someone might comment on it.

```
=INDEX(DATA!U:U,MATCH(A2&" Saturday",DATA!A:A,0))

=sum(INDEX(DATA!U:U,MATCH(A2&" Saturday",DATA!A:A,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Current data are columns A-V? And whats the end result you’re looking for? Post some sample data pf what you’re expecting to sum and the result.

Comment: The data tab has the unique reference in A, morning hours in U, and evening in V. I'm trying to pull these values into AD and AE above which inst hard except for the fact that there are multiple occurrences in the source data that match/index inst picking up

Comment: Sidenote: Please attend your open questions. See if you can accept answers give to close these threads.

Comment: Any ideas? I still can't figure this one out??